# Explicitly instantiating a class template with a list of parameters

Tags: c++

I am trying to instantiate a class template with a whole bunch of different combinations of template parameters which will be decided by some runtime information: https://github.com/ITKTools/ITKTools/blob/newpixeltypeselector/src/binarythinning/binarythinning.cxx . This system works fine (lines 169 - 190), but it is quite verbose. And this is only 2 and 3 dimensions, what if I wanted 2 - 10? This would be pages of code!

Is there anyway to reduce this to say "instantiate all pairs of [these types] and [these dimensions]" or something like that?

I've seen something like this in Boost, but using Boost is unfortunately not an option for this project.

Any pointers?

Thanks!

David

Comment: If you've seen it in Boost, then go read the Boost source code. That should explain fairly well how to do it.

Comment: Haha "read the Boost source code" is not really an answer that will help anyone but elite programmers.

Comment: hah, I was about to give you an example of doing this using Boost when I noticed that.  Oh well.  Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Googling for "typelist" should give some reasonable starting points. Loki also includes this kind of capability, and is a lot smaller (if rather more brain-bending) than Boost.

Comment: I think you can do this (or at least the dimensions part) with Boost.PP. And using Boost.PP is an option for almost *any* project since you'd only have to include the Boost.PP headers, and that's all of it. And since it only requires the preprocessor, compiler compatibility is not an issue (though preprocessor compatibility may be an issue :)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the consensus is "use Boost."